# Getting errors when building C3p0 from source

Tags: java, connection-pooling, c3p0

I downloaded the source  (v 0.9.1.2) and tried building it, first from
command line and then inside an IDE.

I think the problem is setting classpath in the build.properties file.
 Here is my current classpath.  Of course, I've tried various things
here, but all give the same results:

```
j2ee.classpath=C:/glassfishv3/glassfish/lib/j2ee.jar
and tried:
j2ee.jar.base.dir=C:/glassfishv3/glassfish/lib
etc.
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
init-codegen:
[javac] Compiling 6 source files to C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\classes

beangen:
     [echo] Some warnings are expected here. Don't worry about them.

newproxygen:

codegen:

compile-common:
    [javac] Compiling 222 source files to C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\classes
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\codegen\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewProxyConnection.jav
a:1339: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]                             throw SqlUtils.toSQLException("You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!", exc
);
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\codegen\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewProxyConnection.jav
a:1347: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]                             throw parentPooledConnection.handleThrowable( exc );
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\codegen\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewProxyConnection.jav
a:1349: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]                     else throw SqlUtils.toSQLException( exc );
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\codegen\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewProxyConnection.jav
a:1365: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]                             throw SqlUtils.toSQLException("You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!", exc
);
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\codegen\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewProxyConnection.jav
a:1373: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]                             throw parentPooledConnection.handleThrowable( exc );
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\codegen\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewProxyConnection.jav
a:1375: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]                     else throw SqlUtils.toSQLException( exc );
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewPooledConnection.java
:38: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeStatementE
ventListener(javax.sql.StatementEventListener) in javax.sql.PooledConnection
    [javac] public final class NewPooledConnection extends AbstractC3P0PooledConnection{
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\ComboPooledDataSource.java:42
: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperFor(java.lang
.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class ComboPooledDataSource extends AbstractPoolBackedDataSource implements PooledDataSource, S
erializable, Referenceable
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\DriverManagerDataSource.java:
45: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperFor(java.
lang.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class DriverManagerDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSourceBase implements DataSource
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\JndiRefForwardingDataSource.j
ava:47: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.JndiRefForwardingDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperF
or(java.lang.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] final class JndiRefForwardingDataSource extends JndiRefDataSourceBase implements DataSource
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\PoolBackedDataSource.java:28:
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperFor(java.lang.C
lass) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class PoolBackedDataSource extends AbstractPoolBackedDataSource implements PooledDataSource
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.jav
a:39: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeStatemen
tEventListener(javax.sql.StatementEventListener) in javax.sql.PooledConnection
    [javac] public final class C3P0PooledConnection extends AbstractC3P0PooledConnection
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.jav
a:503: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnection.StatementProxyingSetManagedResultSet is not abstract and does not o
verride abstract method updateNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
    [javac]     private static class StatementProxyingSetManagedResultSet extends SetManagedResultSet
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.jav
a:618: ProxyCallableStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method setNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Re
ader) in java.sql.CallableStatement
    [javac]             class ProxyCallableStatement extends FilterCallableStatement implements C3P0ProxyStatement
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.jav
a:655: ProxyPreparedStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method setNClob(int,java.io.Reader) in java
.sql.PreparedStatement
    [javac]             class ProxyPreparedStatement extends FilterPreparedStatement implements C3P0ProxyStatement
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.jav
a:692: ProxyStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method isPoolable() in java.sql.Statement
    [javac]             class ProxyStatement extends FilterStatement implements C3P0ProxyStatement
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NullStatementSetManagedR
esultSet.java:37: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NullStatementSetManagedResultSet is not abstract and does not override abstra
ct method updateNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
    [javac] final class NullStatementSetManagedResultSet extends SetManagedResultSet
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\SetManagedDatabaseMetaDa
ta.java:30: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.SetManagedDatabaseMetaData is not abstract and does not override abstract method ge
tFunctionColumns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in java.sql.DatabaseMetaData
    [javac] final class SetManagedDatabaseMetaData extends FilterDatabaseMetaData
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\SnatchFromSetResultSet.j
ava:30: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.SnatchFromSetResultSet is not abstract and does not override abstract method updateNClo
b(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
    [javac] final class SnatchFromSetResultSet extends FilterResultSet
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\test\FreezableDriverManagerDa
taSource.java:49: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.test.FreezableDriverManagerDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstra
ct method isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class FreezableDriverManagerDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSourceBase implements DataSourc
e
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\util\CloseReportingConnection
Wrapper.java:29: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.util.CloseReportingConnectionWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract
 method createStruct(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[]) in java.sql.Connection
    [javac] public class CloseReportingConnectionWrapper extends FilterConnection
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 21 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build.xml:256: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

EDIT:
Here are the errors I get when building with Java 5:

```
compile-common:
    [javac] Compiling 226 source files to C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build\classes
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NewPooledConnection.jav
:38: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeStatement
ventListener(javax.sql.StatementEventListener) in javax.sql.PooledConnection
    [javac] public final class NewPooledConnection extends AbstractC3P0PooledConnection{
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\ComboPooledDataSource.java:4
: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperFor(java.lan
.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class ComboPooledDataSource extends AbstractPoolBackedDataSource implements PooledDataSource,
erializable, Referenceable
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\DriverManagerDataSource.java
45: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperFor(java
lang.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class DriverManagerDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSourceBase implements DataSource
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\JndiRefForwardingDataSource.
ava:47: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.JndiRefForwardingDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapper
or(java.lang.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] final class JndiRefForwardingDataSource extends JndiRefDataSourceBase implements DataSource
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\PoolBackedDataSource.java:28
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method isWrapperFor(java.lang.
lass) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class PoolBackedDataSource extends AbstractPoolBackedDataSource implements PooledDataSource
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.ja
a:39: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeStateme
tEventListener(javax.sql.StatementEventListener) in javax.sql.PooledConnection
    [javac] public final class C3P0PooledConnection extends AbstractC3P0PooledConnection
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.ja
a:503: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnection.StatementProxyingSetManagedResultSet is not abstract and does not
verride abstract method updateNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
    [javac]     private static class StatementProxyingSetManagedResultSet extends SetManagedResultSet
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.ja
a:618: ProxyCallableStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method setNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.R
ader) in java.sql.CallableStatement
    [javac]             class ProxyCallableStatement extends FilterCallableStatement implements C3P0ProxyStatement
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.ja
a:655: ProxyPreparedStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method setNClob(int,java.io.Reader) in jav
.sql.PreparedStatement
    [javac]             class ProxyPreparedStatement extends FilterPreparedStatement implements C3P0ProxyStatement
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\C3P0PooledConnection.ja
a:692: ProxyStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method isPoolable() in java.sql.Statement
    [javac]             class ProxyStatement extends FilterStatement implements C3P0ProxyStatement
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\NullStatementSetManaged
esultSet.java:37: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NullStatementSetManagedResultSet is not abstract and does not override abstr
ct method updateNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
    [javac] final class NullStatementSetManagedResultSet extends SetManagedResultSet
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\SetManagedDatabaseMetaD
ta.java:30: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.SetManagedDatabaseMetaData is not abstract and does not override abstract method g
tFunctionColumns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in java.sql.DatabaseMetaData
    [javac] final class SetManagedDatabaseMetaData extends FilterDatabaseMetaData
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\impl\SnatchFromSetResultSet.
ava:30: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.SnatchFromSetResultSet is not abstract and does not override abstract method updateNCl
b(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
    [javac] final class SnatchFromSetResultSet extends FilterResultSet
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\test\FreezableDriverManagerD
taSource.java:49: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.test.FreezableDriverManagerDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstr
ct method isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class) in java.sql.Wrapper
    [javac] public final class FreezableDriverManagerDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSourceBase implements DataSour
e
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\src\classes\com\mchange\v2\c3p0\util\CloseReportingConnectio
Wrapper.java:29: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.util.CloseReportingConnectionWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstrac
 method createStruct(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[]) in java.sql.Connection
    [javac] public class CloseReportingConnectionWrapper extends FilterConnection
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 15 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\build.xml:256: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details


Total time: 15 seconds
C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src>java -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\downloads\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src\c3p0-0.9.1.2.src>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to build with Java6, and that won't work.
The 0.9.1.2 version of c3p0 only works with Java5.

You'll need to try building it again with JDK1.5

Unfortunately, the "ant clean" target doesn't clean up 100%, so you'll probably want to delete your folder and start again.

Why are you trying to build from source anyway? 
There's a binary download available, and it looks like you're just complicating things for yourself.

Comment: yes, I am complicating things for myself.... to improve my understanding of connection pooling and object pooling.

Comment: I edited the original question to add errors I get when building with java 5

Comment: The error messages you're getting suggest that ant is still compiling with Java 6. Ant uses various environment variables to pick the JDK to use, so your "java -version" isn't enough to be sure Ant is using a 1.5 JDK. Can you try running "ant -verbose init", and check the fourth line of output. It *should* say "Detected Java version: 1.5 in: ...", but I think it's going to say "Detected Java version: 1.6 in: ..."

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment for a long time.  Thanks.  Ant is indeed using 1.6